# Kafka - TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka connection timeout after the 30000ms.it showing error

```
{ TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms
at new TimeoutError (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/errors/TimeoutError.js:6:9)
at Timeout.timeoutId._createTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:1007:14)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:535:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:479:7) message: 'Request timed out after 30000ms' }

Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient broker is now ready
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client updated internal metadata
Kafka Producer is connected and ready.
----->data PRODUCT_REF_TOKEN { hash:
   '0x964f714829cece2c5f57d5c8d677c251eff82f7fba4b5ba27b4bd650da79a954',
  success: 'true' }
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient compressing messages if needed
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client createBroker 127.0.0.1:9092
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient missing apiSupport waiting until broker is ready...
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient waitUntilReady [BrokerWrapper 127.0.0.1:9092 (connected: true) (ready: false) (idle: false) (needAuthentication: false) (authenticated: false)]
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:24 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client socket closed 127.0.0.1:9092 (hadError: true)
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:25 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client reconnecting to 127.0.0.1:9092
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:25 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client createBroker 127.0.0.1:9092
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:25 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client socket closed 127.0.0.1:9092 (hadError: true)
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:26 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client reconnecting to 127.0.0.1:9092
Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:10:26 GMT kafka-node:KafkaClient kafka-node-client createBroker 127.0.0.1:9092
```

docker-compose.yml for kafka setup please let me know if any setup or properties need to be setup.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  api:
    image: opschain-sapi
    restart: always
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:80
    env_file:
      - ./truffle/contracts.env
      - ./.env
    external_links:
      - ganachecli-private
      - ganachecli-public
    networks:
      - opschain_network

  graphql-api:
    build:
      context: ./graphql-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - 9007:80
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - graphql-api-watch
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./graphql-api/dist:/app/dist:delegated
      - ./graphql-api/src:/app/src:delegated
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: api.blockchain.docker
      PORT: 80
      OFFCHAIN_DB_URL: mongodb://root:password@mongodb:27017
      OFFCHAIN_DB_NAME: opschain-wallet
      OFFCHAIN_DB_USER_COLLECTION: user
      JWT_PASSWORD: 'supersecret'
      JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME: 86400000
      BLOCKCHAIN_API: api
    networks:
      - opschain_network

  graphql-api-watch:
    build:
      context: ./graphql-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run watch
    volumes:
      - ./graphql-api/src:/app/src:delegated
      - ./graphql-api/dist:/app/dist:delegated
    networks:
      - opschain_network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017 
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: opschain-wallet
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    networks:
      - opschain_network

  ui:
    build:
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./ui/public:/app/public:delegated
      - ./ui/src:/app/src:delegated
    depends_on:
      - graphql-api
    networks:
      - opschain_network
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: tmna.csc.docker
      REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL: http://localhost:8080
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
  test:
    build: ./test
    volumes:
      - ./test/postman:/app/postman:delegated
    networks:
      - opschain_network
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./pub-sub/zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./pub-sub/zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog
    networks:
      - opschain_network

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      # KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "cat:1:1"
    volumes:
      - ./pub-sub/zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - api
    networks:
      - opschain_network

networks:
  opschain_network:
    external: true
```

*in the above compose file i have exposed the port 9092 and zookeper port 2181. Exactly i am not sure what the issue is*

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const config = require('./configUtils');


function sendMessage({ topic, message }) {
    let Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: config.kafka.host,autoConnect: true}),
    producer = new Producer(client);
    producer.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Kafka Producer is connected and ready.');
    console.log('----->data',topic,message)
    producer.send(
      [
        {
          topic,

          messages: [JSON.stringify(message)],

        }
      ],
      function(_err, data){
          console.log('--err',_err)
       console.log('------->message sent from kafka',data);

      }
    );
  });

  producer.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


}

module.exports = sendMessage;
```

producer file where it connects to the kafka client and on ready it produces the message

Comment: Where is your client running (inside Docker network, or not)? What broker hostname and port is it connecting to?

Comment: yes it is running inside docker.

Comment: What broker hostname and port is your application connecting to?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue using the landoop/fast-data-dev image with docker-compose. I was able to solve it by making sure the ADV_HOST environment variable was configured to be the name of the kafka service (e.g. kafka1). Then setting the kafkaHost option to the name of service. (e.g. kafka1:9092).

The environment variable for your kafka image appears to be "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME".